# "Recent viewed product" template customization in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2.5, I have showed "recent viewed products" on product detail page via Widget.
But I want to customize "recent views product" template.
Actually now they don't show price if product is configurable.
I searched and get template file in this path:-

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html

But this file contain knockout js format.
I guess there is some other files (like .phtml).
Please suggest me how can I customize its template.

Thank You

Comment: Can you update your widget code to your question?

Comment: Hello Sukumar, I didn't get widget code. Actually i just called recently viewed widget from admin panel.

Comment: I have tried and price is showing for all product types.

Comment: Please look this screenshot-link   https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3606996/5356ba586fe408873c1c98167a4cd908

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of widget options?

Comment: And please can you navigate me its template path, So i can customize it.

Comment: Widget option screenshot https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3607014/74ab99aca974294404e926b7a3b0424b

Comment: Settings looks ok and you are in the right template path. If you want to know from where data comes then goto module-catalog/Ui directory. Here you will get the Dataprovider and component. Datas are rendering from here.

Comment: I checked, but i didn't get answer for listing.html file script like they use <fastForEach args="data: getRegion('general-area'), as: '$col'" >
                            <render args="$col.getBody()"/>              How can i get value of GENERAL-AREA ?

Comment: Hello Guys, Anyone can help me please.